# Pass a handler from class to component in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want to pass a click handle (handleDeleteUser) to other component, from user.js to DropDownUserTool.js actually:

**User.js**

```js
handleDeleteUser = (id) => {
  alert(id);
};
...
// in render
User.data.map(function (User, i) {
  return (
    <DropDownUserTool
      id={User.id}
      click={(e) => {
        this.handleDeleteUser(e);
      }}
    />
  );
});
```

**DropDownUserTool.js**

```js
const DropDownUserTool = (props) => {
  return (
    <ButtonDropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle color="secondary" caret>
        tools
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem>
          <Link to={"/User/Edit/" + props.id}>Edit</Link>
        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => props.click(props.id)}>
          Delete
        </DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </ButtonDropdown>
  );
};
```

But after click it return an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleDeleteUser')

On this line:

<DropDownUserTool id={User.id} click={(e) => {this.handleDeleteUser(e)}}/>

Comment: Have you tried passing just `this.handleDeleteUser`?

Comment: @testing_22 yep, got error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleDeleteUser')`

Comment: So the component where handleDeleteUser is defined is a class component, I assume, since you're referencing `this`?

Comment: @FranCarstens yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reach `this` inside `map`, just define `this` ! inside `render` before loop:

```
let realthis = this;
```

Then call your handler like this:

```
<DropDownUserTool id={User.id} click={(e) => {realthis.handleDeleteUser(e)}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing your map you're using a standard function call and losing your context. Use an arrow function instead.

```js
class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
    };
  }

  handleDeleteUser = (id) => alert(id);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // this needs to be an arrow function
        // that way you won't change the context of `this`
        {this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <DropDownUserTool
              id={item.id}
              key={item.id}
              handleDelete={this.handleDeleteUser }
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const DropDownUserTool = ({ handleDelete, id }) => (
  <button onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}>Delete</button>
);
```

Comment: Error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleDeleteUser')`

Comment: Shot in the dark here, you're refencing "User.id" in the "User" component. Where is "id" defined? If it's on User, it should be this.id. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: it take all data such `id` and etc from `User` object `User.data.map(function(User, i){` since `User` got data from `api`. Also, I got `id` successfully on `DropDownUserTool.js` , it work on edit link.

Comment: You're right, not sure how I missed that. Glad you got it to work.

Comment: Made an update.